# Programming in C Evaluating characters from a string

Tags: c, string, if-statement, char

apologies in advance if this has already been answered on this site. I'm trying to compare a character from a string in C with another character. Here is some code as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char your_name[];
int main(){
    printf("Please enter your name:\n");
    scanf("%s",your_name);
    if (your_name[0]=="A"){
        printf("Your name begins with A!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Your name does not begin with A!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work and I don't know why. If i put in 'Anthony' when prompted I can printf the character your_name[0] and it will display 'A' but the if statement always fails. I've tried using strcmp and that didn't work (although I didn't think it would.)

What should I be using instead to make this evaluation?

Comment: `'A'` is not the same as `"A"`. Grab a beginner's tutorial, stuff like that will be nicely explained there. But this fits the "too localized" category very well.

Answer (score 4):

`"A"` is a string. Your intention is to compare characters. Try comparing with `'A'` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `'A'` instead of `"A"`.

```
if (your_name[0]=='A'){}
                  ^ ^
//Use single quotes here
```

The first one is a character literal while the second one is a string literal, and since you're trying to compare characters, what you used isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

The character should be specified in single quotes.  Your `if` statement should read

```
if (your_name[0]=='A')
```